# Java - Analizing Spectrum of a song - output on certain peaks

Tags: java, audio, spectrum

I am relatively new to Java, and I have never dealt with sound before, but as a school project we need to code a program (Major project for the year) and I need to process a song, and output certain words on certain frequency hitmarkers (so if it hits a beat, output "beat", if it hits like 13596Hz on the spectrum, output "high sound" and so on).

How is this possible? I have had a look at JTransforms an jMIR, but they do not make sense to me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.